# How do I get User status over a certain amount of time with Microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've been looking around for a bit now and can't seem to find anything related.

I'm trying to get a users "presence" object or something similar for a full day.

I've tried to use delta on the presence call but it doesn't seem to be supported atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph.

In Microsoft Graph to get a  user's [presence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/presence?view=graph-rest-beta) information, you need to have delegated permissions **Presence.Read, Presence.Read.All** and HTTP get query request looks like below

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/66825e03-7ef5-42da-9069-724602c31f6b/presence
```

***The output for the above query below:***

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('66825e03-7ef5-42da-9069-724602c31f6b')/presence/$entity",
    "id": "3ec9bb05-dd2e-4b36-87b0-3a855f4b82ed",
    "availability": "Offline",
    "activity": "Offline"
}
```

Please refer to Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#permissions) for more details.

Comment: I've already found this call problem is i cant get the data overtime only the current status of a user

Comment: Hi @jesperjakobsen, Correct me if I was wrong. Are you trying to get users past sign-in information?

Comment: Yes for example i want a specifics user status for this whole week.

Comment: @jesperjakobsen, Currently there is no inbuilt mechanism in AAD to get user status like that. Since AAD stores only last login information available in audit logs and we can also retrieve it through Ms Graph. But You can achieve this status of the user for the entire week by automation scripts.

Comment: Hmm, thought they would have it added since microsoft teams already has it, see example here where it says he was last online an hour ago: https://imgur.com/a/ZZxg0PQ

Comment: Yes , You can get the last login information from audit logs but not every login information.As I said you need to use automation scripting to achieve every login info.

Comment: How do you get the last login information? since the presence call only returns current sign in status?

Comment: @jesperjakobsen, you will get it from  'activityDateTime' property in [directoryAudit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/directoryaudit?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)